# How to replace cursor for set-based approach?

Tags: sql, sql-server, cursor, database-performance, query-performance

What would be a more efficient way to replace a RABR situation into a set-based one, where there is a procedure that receives two parameters, a code, and a date, and the result is inserted into a temp table.

```
CREATE TABLE #RESULTADO(CODE INT, DATA DATETIME);
DECLARE @CODE
SELECT @CODE = MIN(CODIGO)
FROM TABELACOMDADOS
WHERE CODE <> ''
AND CODE IS NOT NULL

WHILE @CODE IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO #RESULTADO
    EXECUTE PR_PROCESSACALCULO @CODE, @DATA;
    -- NEXT VALUE FOR THE LOOP
    SELECT @CODE = MIN(CODIGO)
    FROM TABELACOMDADOS
    WHERE CODE > @CODE
    ORDER BY CODE;
END;
```

I have tried to replace the current cursor with this while loop, but the total duration is 2 minutes minus only.

Comment: as it is `cursor` or `while loop` you will still need to execute the stored procedure for each code & data. Best way is to change the stored procedure to accept  `table valued paramter`

Comment: @Squirrel Thanks for your attention, how to pass to the procedure a table-valued parameter? please, would you provide an example? Thanks in advanced.

Comment: please refer to the documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/use-table-valued-parameters-database-engine?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and an explanation of what the code is supposed to do would help.  You don't need a cursor for this.